# Logstash parse string into single event with multiple fields

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have as an input a string:

```
XXXX NNN TIMESTAMP\r\nYYYY NNN TIMESTAMP\r\nZZZZ NNN TIMESTAMP
```

How to parse/filter/transform this input into single event with fields

```
{
   "XXXX" : NNN,
   "YYYY" : NNN,
   "ZZZZ" : NNN
}
```

For me it's important to have it as a single event

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
filter {     
    mutate {
           gsub => ["message", "TIMESTAMP\r\n", ""]
         }
    grok {         
      match => [ "message", "(?:XXXX %{WORD:XXXX}) (?:YYYY\s%{WORD:YYYY})\s(?:ZZZZ %{WORD:ZZZZ})" ]
    }
    }
```